# Javascript file detected as text file hence no no syntax coloring and check working

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin

I have installed STS 3.9.17. I have created basic spring boot application.
Whenever I am creating javascript file it is working as text file only that's syntax coloring and syntax checking according toJS not working in STS tool.
I tried to change setting in Preferences -> client JS -> Enable syntax coloring but it disabled.
I tried to install codemix as well as web developer tool. I am getting error in that also.

Getting following error while trying to install codemix or web developer tools:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  Software being installed: a.jre.javase 9.0.0
  Software currently installed: Spring Tool Suite 3.9.17.202106211301-RELEASE-e418 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.9.17.202106211301-RELEASE-e418)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite 3.9.17.202106211301-RELEASE-e418 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.9.17.202106211301-RELEASE-e418)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; a.jre.javase [9.0.0,9.0.0]
```

Please let me know solutions.
Thanks!
[web developer tool error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrK5i.png)
[Spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgyzG.png)

Comment: You need to install some kind of JavaScript support.
Somethink like this: https://eclipse.dev/webtools/jsdt/
Use the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: Tried but getting error while installing . Updating my question with images

Comment: Better avoid plugins like codemix or other plugins from the same vendor as they patch Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). The problem seems to be that you run your quite old version (which is more than two years and 9 releases behind) of Eclipse with Java 9, but current STS and Eclipse versions require Java 17 or higher to run. Consider do a fresh installation of current Eclipse or STS containing Java 17 and latest JavaScript support via Eclipse Wild Web Developer.